# Flag for acceptance

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, accepted-answer

There are a lot of questions asked by new users that get an answer that works, where they state in the comments that it solves their issue, then they leave and never come back without accepting the answer. This leaves questions with accepted answers in the unanswered queue even if the user has stated that it solves the issue.

I propose an option to flag for acceptance which will only be shown if

- if the user has commented that it solves their issue
- The user has not accepted the answer within a certain time period
- The user has not been active on the site for a certain time period

**I honestly don't care about the rep**

I just want to stop these questions from clogging the unanswered queue

**EDIT**

I did not know that questions that have an answer with an upvote get removed from the queue. Sorry for asking.

For future viewers who find this while wondering what to do when they see a question in the unanswered queue with a good answer, upvote it to remove it from the queue

Comment: **Acceptance is the sole domain of the OP**. This *has* been asked before, many, many times. You need to provide a much stronger case as to why we should be allowing such flags.

Comment: Edited to include after a certain time period. The user has already stated that the answer solves their issue, but in most cases will leave and not come back. Leaving these questions in the unanswered queue

Comment: You may leave a friendly comment with your answer, inviting the OP to accept it and even earn 2 pts rep with that action. If they don't come back or aren't interested in participating the site, there's no way to force them.

Comment: Yes but the questions clog up the unanswered queue. I honestly don't care about the rep, I just care about the issue being solved and removed from the queue.

Comment: @humble.rumble If your answer got an upvote, it is removed from the queue. If it didn't... then should we really force an acceptance when no one in the community thinks its vote worthy?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I didn't know that answers get removed from the queue if they get upvotes. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Here's one example to help build a stronger case; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544447/malloc-keeps-returning-the-same-addresss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question being "answered" is simply determined by if there is an upvoted answer on it (or an acceptance mark, presumably).

So for purposes of getting a question "out of the queue" this request doesn't do much. To the little bit it *would* accomplish, I repeat my comment:

> If [the post] didn't [get an upvote]... then should we really force
>   an acceptance when no one in the community thinks its vote worthy?