# Auto mark answer for question which are not accepted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Accepting the answers of question which are old around 6 - 12 months old on following clause:

1. Number of vote ups for that answer
2. Number of edits and comments on answer
3. Number of down vote answer to be excluded regardless of the total number of vote
4. Comment of the person asking question (like it works) can be considered

This could be carried out by a community bot to mark the answer.

### **Other solution**

- Most correct ask can be checked by the moderator or their majority vote count (Time spend on this is it worth it for moderator)
- possible to add it in review queue

**Reason for request:**

While browsing through question on so there are too many answer which are not accepted and which makes the best possible answer to the question not clear.The person which answers the question has to comment on the answer to accept it.
How can we create great system for this type of question?

Comment: Accepted answers only mean anything to the OP.  I worry for the person that *only* reads the accepted answer if other answers exist.

Comment: @gnat the question asked was with a view to involve moderator to check the answer i am asking possible solution to solve unaccepted answer we can use other users to vote to mark answer as the person asking question has not accepted the answer yet

Comment: dont just down vote the answer its not duplicate

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277918, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294815, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295886

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå accepted its duplicate flag for moderator to delete it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accepted answers don't necessarily refer to the "best possible answer to the question". They only refer to the one that the person asking the question feels worked best for them.

Vote count is a far better measurement of "best possible answer" than acceptance. While they often converge, they don't always.

Comment: its does not get the reward for the people who have answered the question  that is point i want to raise

Comment: @saurabhkamble: I recognize that. But it is irrelevant all the same. The purpose of SO is to build a database of knowledge. So long as the highest voted answers are of good quality and provide useful information, the site is doing its job. Accepted answers are a useful tool, but not essential to this.

Comment: They aren't the "best possible answer to the question", but are considered as such by users (many users).

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not going to work!.

> Why is the current system good / non-chaotic?

The OP is the one who accepts the answer. Nobody has the right to say anything to the OP. He can select the answer which he thinks is good even though others might consider that answer to be **completely useless**.

> What would happen if people other than the OP were allowed to do this
>   instead of the OP?

1. I would think one answer is perfect and try arguing with others who
   disagree.
2. There will be several questions on SO everyday asking *was my
   selected answer the right one?*

PS : Mods already have too many things on their plates now, adding this unnecessary burden can only cause them more pain.

As far as questions without an accepted answer go, we could send the OP a notification that he has some questions which have no accepted answers once a week (assuming that the OP will do something about it.). I've seen cases where the OP hasn't logged in into SO for over 4 years now and he has some questions without accepted answers.

Comment: I take umbrage with "nobody has the right to say anything to the OP".  It's their prerogative if they accept an answer, but if the answer is *actively* harmful or dangerous, this should be made as explicit as possible.

Comment: *but if the answer is actively harmful or dangerous* - If you are talking about *valid answers which could be dangerous in certain situations*, Yes, we atleast tell the OP that it is dangerous. That doesn't just apply to *accepted answers*,. Any answer that is dangerous should be treated that way :)