# Threshold for becoming accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Sometimes one gives the right answer to some question and there are many upvotes (maybe including the question author) but the question is not marked as the right answer. I know that can happen due to forgetfulness from question author, or maybe there's not yet a right answer, or there are many right answers.

**But shouldn't an answer, when reaches a *threshold* of upvotes, be considered the right one?**

This would help people who search for the question to understand that specific question has a right answer, and also would reward the answer's author.

Maybe a *threshold* is not the best way of achieving it, but I guess at some point a question should have a right answer. What do you think?

Comment: sometimes the answer with big number of upvotes isn't *correct* and the accurate one is at the bottom with less upvotes

Comment: FYI: Votes in meta do not affect your reputation, and are many times used to express disagreement. Also, "OP" is usually meant to designate the "original poster", not the "original post". So "OP's author" would not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Related: [Auto mark answer for question which are not accepted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311711/auto-mark-answer-for-question-which-are-not-accepted) and also the answer here: [Can moderators make an answer accepted to close the post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262672/can-moderators-make-an-answer-accepted-to-close-the-post)

Comment: "*I guess at some point a question should have a right answer*" why? It's entirely possible that multiple answers are posted and *none* of them is correct. For example, each only handles one aspect of the question, thus no answer is *complete*. Or each answer could just be misinterpreting the question.

Comment: I disagree with this premise, with *one* exception: in the case that Jon Skeet answers the question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels doesn't he already have the unlimited ability to accept his own answers?

Comment: I mean... "accepted answer" means "answer the OP says works for them". I find that "forcing" this at a certain threshold makes no sense and devalues the whole idea of accepted answer. Now with that being said, I think the checkmark doesn't have its place on our side...

Answer (score 0):

I'd first ask yourself what the significance of an "accepted" answer is (outside of that +15 rep).

In my experience, it puts the answer at the top of the answer list and lets future visitors know that this answer is credible and probably what they're looking for.

The funny thing is, if one answer has 5x the upvotes of all the other answers on a question, those upvotes will do the *same exact thing* as accepting the answer will! So what benefit do we gain from taking the choice of accepting an answer away from the question asker in such cases? In my opinion: nothing.

Comment: Will it be on top as well?

Comment: If it has the most upvotes? Then yes @sam (assuming readers haven't changed their orderby criteria, which I think most don't).

Comment: But if there's an accepted answer, this one will be the top!

Comment: It was my assumption you were talking about the case where there is no accepted answer. Do you actually mean you want to *change* the accepted answer away from the OP's choice to a different answer with more votes @sam?

Comment: Not really, though that could be discussed (the OP could not see the advantages of one answer relatively to the accepted answer). It's not the same thing when you preview the questions, as this one does not have yet a solution, officially. But it's not a big deal.