Should self-Q&A questions auto-accept the answer?
Should self-Q&A questions auto-accept the answer?
After all, the answer I wrote to my own question is, in 99.9999% of cases, the answer that worked best for me.

Related: Why can't you accept your own answer immediately?

@AbdulAzizBarkat That makes sense if the user asking happened to find the answer shortly after asking, but not for Q&A (At least it doesn't seem necessary to me)

@Daviid That question has the exact same scenario (I asked a question just to share an answer) as yours, so yes, it does make sense for Q&A-style questions.

As far as it being a duplicate rather than merely related...ehhhhh, this is a feature request asking for a change and that's a discussion asking why it is the way that it is.

What is a "Q&A style question"? As opposed to... what, a question that doesn't have an answer? Well, I suppose it would be difficult to accept an answer in that case...

@KarlKnechtel I believe that's referring to the Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style checkbox on the non-wizard Ask Question page.

As Ryan said, my question is related to the Q&A checkbox, accepting your own answer when you found the answer shortly after posting the question is slightly different.

Note that the related question starts off with (emphasis added) "Occasionally I ask a question for the sole purpose of sharing the answer", which really is the same scenario.

Yes, maybe the OP didn't know about the Q&A checkbox or it wasn't implemented in 2014? (Going off question and answer timestamps in the question they link, which are not the same)

At the very least, there's a minimum rep of 15 to allow instant self-answer.

@AndrewT. that link pretty much directly answers my question "officially", thanks. (I still think it wouldn't be bad to auto-accept exclusively in the case of checking the Q&A checkbox, which I also think should give or take any reputation)

I once (or maybe more) provided a better answer to a self-Q&A and the OP accepted mine in the end. So your 99.999% is not very accurate. I would decrease it to 80% or even less.

No
There is no need.
If another answer is posted, it might even be better than the self-answer.
Otherwise, it is trivial to just accept the self-answer.
An auto-accept does not significantly improve anything.

it might even be better than the self-answer. yes, but the point of someone doing a Q&A style is, to my understanding, that the user had a question and found a solution which was the best for him and wants to share that knowledge.  Having the answer auto-accepted shows other people with the same problem that "Hey! I had the same problem as you and here's an answer that actually works", if a better answer comes than the OP can accept it or not. As stated here

@Daviid irrelevant, really. Somebody self-answers, then another user answers shows up. The original author might still find that they prefer the new answer and thus accept that one. It might show an angle the original author didn't consider or whatever. Again, if you wish to claim that everybody who self-answers is vehemently against considering any other answer for acceptance - fine. So what? They have to spend something in the order of 30 seconds to accept their own self-answer rather than another one. I fail to see the auto-acceptance as an improvement.

Irrelevant is how I would describe the acceptance checkbox in general :)

if you wish to claim that everybody who self-answers is vehemently against considering any other answer for acceptance - fine never have I said that, in fact you can read if a better answer comes than the OP can accept it or not. at the end of my comment.

@Gimby While I fully agree with you, I think it's a topic for another time. I also face a lot of resistance any time I suggest it, so here I tried not to.

@Daviid OK, so your first comment amounts to nothing, then: It opposes my suggestion that other answers can be accepted but then concludes that other answers can be accepted. So, on the whole I don't see why it's worth discussing. I don't you providing any compelling reason why auto-accepting self-answers should be added. At best, your argument amounts to "OP would do it anyway...but they can also accept another answer" which is not a strong argument, IMO.

It opposes my suggestion that other answers can be accepted but then concludes that other answers can be accepted.  No, I have at no point said that the asking user would not accept a better answer, and if any of my answer has been interpreted that way it wasn't my intention. WHY auto accept in the Q&A case? Because it shows others with the same problem that the answer actually works a better answer comes and the asker accepts it? Good. A better answer comes and the asker does not accepts it? Good, at least there's an accepted answer that other users can easily identify as a solution.

Yes, Q&A-style posts' answers should be auto-accepted.

I'm shocked! It doesn't auto-accept. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311711/auto-mark-answer-for-question-which-are-not-accepted

well then you are making the mistake of thinking meta and the main site follow the same rules. Naturally they do not since their purposes are different.

@Gimby are they auto-accepted on the main site?  I'm genuinely unsure since I've only done it once...

@RyanM I hope not. But even if they were, it would be pointless to do a test on meta thinking you'd get the same results.

@RyanM I also don't know, I tried it here because I didn't want to spam the main site but I just tried and it does not auto accept

@Gimby I hope not.  Why? From https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged. which, with the previously linked question and answer would make anyone think that auto-accepting the answer in Q&A is a matter of fact.

On the main site you need to wait 48 hours regardless before being able to accept your own answer. So it most definitely wont auto-accept immediately.

@Cuzy I don't think acceptance is a barrier to edits or other input, but it is definitely relevant that someone might post a better answer and you might decide to accept that instead.

@Daviid I rebel against anything which is done with zero thought. Hitting the button must be a deliberate act.

@Gimby checking the box is deliberate tho. "Hey this answer works and I want everyone to know from the get go"

This quite frankly is a terrible answer as all it is, is a naked statement made without any text that supports its conclusion and thus risking its deletion, since as written, it adds no use to the site. It may be possible to improve this answer, if the OP is willing.
